# Receiving complex data via WebAPI action

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, custom-model-binder

I'm needing a way to convert a complex web request into .Net objects. I understand that WebAPI uses a default model binder, and that for complicated data, a custom model binder is needed.

**Objects**

```vb
Public Class LapMobileModel
    Public Property Type As Integer
    Public Property EndTime As String
    Public Property StartTime As String
End Class

Public Class RaceMobileModel
    Public Property RaceName As String
    Public Property UserId As Integer
    Public Property Laps As IEnumerable(Of LapMobileModel)
    Public Property numberOfRacers As String
    Public Property PreRacePosition As String
    Public Property PostRacePosition As String
End Class

Public Class RaceListMobileModel
    Public Property RaceList As IEnumerable(Of RaceMobileModel)
End Class
```

**Action** (in an ApiController)

```vb
Public Function SyncLapData(ByVal raceList As RaceListMobileModel) As String
    'stuff
    Return "OK"
End Function
```

And I have the skeleton of a custom model binder:

```vb
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.Web.Http.ModelBinding
Imports System.Web.Http.Controllers


Public Class EventDataModelBinder
    Implements IModelBinder

    Public Function BindModel(actionContext As HttpActionContext, 
                              bindingContext As ModelBindingContext) 
                              As Boolean Implements IModelBinder.BindModel
    End Function
End Class
```

**Questions:**

How do I use the `actionContext` to get to the data I need to build the `RaceListMobileModel`?

How do I properly store it in the `bindingContext`?

Right now, the data is being sent via a POST with JSON content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web api doesn't use model binding to bind data from request body. You should take a look of parameter binding instead. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/05/11/webapi-parameter-binding-under-the-hood.aspx

For the json content, web api uses json.net serializer as default to bind the model. It supports nested models or collections. So I don't see anything unsupported in your models. Did you encounter any issue when deserializing a json? Or you have some special logic when binding the data?

Comment: Do'H! I was anticipating a problem that never showed up! Thanks a lot! Deserializing worked fine.